# Substitution $t=x^{2}$ in indefinite integrals

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I've a doubt regarding the substitution $t=x^{2}$ in indefinite integrals.
I know that it is not bijective and therefore it is not possible to obtain an explicit expression of $x$ and of $dx$
But there are some cases in which it is not necessary to express the $x$
For example

$\int \frac{x}{x^{4}-4x^{2}+3} dx$

Let $t=x^{2}$ then $dt=2x dx$ and so

$\int \frac{1}{2(t^{2}-4t+3)} dt$

While in other situations it is not possible to do it

$\int \sqrt{x^2-4} dx$

Is there a particular reason for that? I can't understand completely why sometimes it is allowed and other times is not

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's always "allowed" provided your substitution is well-defined. Whether or not it helps simplify the problem is another story

Comment: Of course it's explicit.  But you have to be careful of whether $x > 0$ or $x < 0$.  If you're substituting $t = x^2$ in an integral where $x > 0$, then $x = \sqrt{t}$ and $dx = dt/(2 \sqrt{t})$.  If $x < 0$, then $x = -\sqrt{t}$ and $dx = - dt/(2 \sqrt{t})$.

Comment: A very good example is when you are integrating for $x$ from $-1$ to $1$. Using your substitution would imply that $t$ now runs from $1$ to......$1$. Now something should tell you that this can't be right. My remark in addition to Robert's general observation.The fourth degree polynomial in the denominator of the OP's example is factorable (over the reals) but had the denominator been $x^4+x^2+2$ then integrating from $-1$ to $1$ certainly would be an interesting feat.

Comment: The substitution $\int_{-1}^1 x\,dx = \int_1^1 \,dt=0$ is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks! Surely it doesn't help many times! But if I make this substitution in a indefinite integral where $x$ can be positive or negative I have to split the two cases $x>0$ and $x<0$ for taking $+\sqrt{t}$ or $-\sqrt{t}$ but then, supposing that it helps, I would get two different antiderivatives?